# Why doesn't my heir inherit my wife's titles?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

So I'm playing as the Emperor of Britannia, and I'm trying to get Scotland into the fold at the moment. So I thought hey, let me marry my son to the duchess of Moray so that his son, my future character can inherit her titles as well as mine (I have done this before).

But now I'm playing as my son, who is still married to the duchess of Moray (so now my wife), and they have had three kids, two girls and a boy last. Now the boy is my heir, obviously as my succession laws are Agnatic-Cognatic Primogeniture, but for some reason my wife's heir is my daughter, with the second in line being my other daughter, and the third in line is some other random I've never heard of!

I've checked her succession laws and she is also Agnatic-Cognatic Primogeniture, so her male child should be her heir? I don't understand.

Comment: What's the Crown Authority in the Kingdom of Scotland?

Comment: How do i check?? but i suspect that must be the issue then!

Comment: Open the De Jure Kingdoms view and mouse over Scotland.

Comment: Yip, thats the issue! The bastards have got absolute crown authority.. there goes that plan haha time to take scotland one county at a time :( thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem. I'm going to add this as an answer anyway.

Comment: I've been staring at my computer screen too long... I totally saw that "**l**" as an "**i**"! XD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Scotland has High or Absolute Crown authority. This means that titles in Scotland cannot pass from the realm though inheritance. This affects De Jure Scotland, which includes Moray. As the Emperor of Britannia, you cannot inherit it as it would pass into a different realm.

You still have options. When your mother dies and your sister inherits, you should still get a weak claim. As a male, you can press this against a female ruler and take Moray that way.

Alternatively, if you don't feel like declaring war on your own sister, she'll probably be willing to swear fealty. She's in your De Jure lands, is two ranks below you and is the same culture.

Comment: I see, but I'll have to declare war because Moray is currently a vassal to the King of Lotharingia, who is also King of Scotland.. Thansk for the help!